# Does it make more sense to install Android Studio on my device, old version or current version?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

my computer has I7 8565u, MX130, 16 Gb Ram. I want to install Android Studio. Is it more stable to install the latest version or to install any version from 2019?

I couldn't decide which path to follow.

Please help me....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It might help if you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and other pages in the help center. In its current state, the question risks being [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for being opinion-based.

Comment: Can you, please, edit the question to tell us why you are having trouble deciding?

Comment: Considering the specifications of your computer (i7 8565u, MX130, 16GB RAM), it should be able to handle the latest version of Android Studio without any issues.

Comment: Old versions may expect online resources that no longer exist, so just use the latest version.